# how can I distinguish several columns apart based on strings

Tags: r

I have a data like this one

```
df<- structure(list(`1` = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Het", "Het1-Het2", "Homo", "No"), class = "factor"), 
    `2` = structure(c(4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Het", "Het1-Het2", "Het2", "Homo", "No"), class = "factor"), 
    `3` = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Het", "Het1-Het2", "Homo", "No"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

I am trying to see what is the differences between the 3 columns 
for example how many NO is in the first which are not in the second or third.the same for het and other strings

Comment: Have you thought about logical comparisons? df$`1` == "No" & (df$`2` != "No"|df$`3` != "No") gives you the Nos in the first column that aren't in the second or third.

Comment: Also, just to let you know, it is not good R practice to name your column starting with (or only consisting of) a number. And, in the future, it is always helpful to include your attempt to solve the problem so people can possibly address specific issues with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this with the `table()` function and ordering by frequency:

```
out = data.frame(table(df))
> out[order(out$Freq, decreasing = T), ]  # Partial output given
          X1        X2        X3 Freq
55      Homo      Homo      Homo    5
60        No        No      Homo    5
79      Homo        No        No    4
9        Het      Het2       Het    2
54 Het1-Het2      Homo      Homo    2
56        No      Homo      Homo    2
59      Homo        No      Homo    2
76        No      Homo        No    2
1        Het       Het       Het    1
26 Het1-Het2 Het1-Het2 Het1-Het2    1
2  Het1-Het2       Het       Het    0
3       Homo       Het       Het    0
...
```

For example, the `Freq` of 5 on the first row means that there are 5 occurences where we observe `Homo` in `X1`, `X2` and `X3`.

We can interpret a `Freq` of 4 in the third row to imply that there are 4 occurences where `X1` is `No`, `X2` is `No` and `X3` is `Homo`.

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer

Comment: @Learner, great thank you. glad that i was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you could just filter the values you want:

```
df %>%
  filter(`1` == "No",
         `2` != "No" & `3` != "No")
   1    2    3
1 No Homo Homo
2 No Homo Homo
```

or

```
filter(df, `1` == "No", `2` != "No" & `3` != "No")
```

Use `tally` to count them

```
df %>%
  filter(`1` == "No",
         `2` != "No" & `3` != "No") %>%
  tally()
  n
1 2
```

Of course, @Luis's solution is simpler (preferred in my book) once you modify to meet your conditions (i.e., `&` not `|` for columns 2 and 3). Well the modification is assuming I read your request correctly:

```
df[df$`1` == "No" & (df$`2` != "No" & df$`3` != "No"),]
    1    2    3
9  No Homo Homo
16 No Homo Homo

sum(df$`1` == "No" & (df$`2` != "No" & df$`3` != "No"))
[1] 2
```

Comment: I liked your answer. Thanks